# Keep Pakoras Crisp

Tags: storage-method, frying, indian-cuisine, catering

What's the best way to keep [pakoras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakora) crisp until being served? I am planning to make pakoras for a party and will not have time to make it as the guests arrive, which is why I would like to make it a few hours ahead and serve upon arrival. Will keeping them in a warm oven help? If so, at what temperature?

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8711/what-technique-should-i-use-to-make-latkes-for-a-party-so-that-i-dont-have-to-st

Comment: when latkes are made with urd flour and spinach, that's related. Otherwise, the pakoras have to be made by Jitendra Cohen ...

Comment: Adding little rice powder will make it crisp.

Answer (score 2):

Make them and wrap each batch in aluminium foil. Warm them in an oven at 140 deg C for about 20 min to an hour before serving,  - same for onion bajhis. They will get too crispy if not wrapped. Don't drain the oil off before wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not serving them right away, I like to double-fry them to make the pakoras nice and crispy. I'd then follow James Barrie's suggestion and keep them in the oven, wrapped in aluminum foil - might bump up the heat to around 150 deg C though.